# After use seo url friendly opencart it shows pages out of website ; localhost page

Tags: seo

Please I have problem about seo url friendly in opencart

I installed `OpenCart 1.5.5.1` on 
appserv `(PHP Version 5.2.6 Apache/2.2.8 (Win32))`
and renamed `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`  ,I checked that mod-rewrite is enabled.

I test 2 topic :

1 If enabled `SEO URL(Settings->Server)`
->I set key `word = about_us` on admin pages already
after open about us page it shows first page of appserv server

2 If diseabled `SEO URL(Settings->Server)`
->after open about us page it shows `index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4`"  -> it shows correct page.

I try to use `opencart 15.6.4` it's same problem. 
What I do wrong ? please help me to solve it. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following in your .htaccess file:

> RewriteBase /

needs to be changed as

> RewriteBase /**your_project_name/**